# Python relative imports in multiple classes

Tags: python, import, path

I get an ImportError because of wrong path when doing multiple imports in Python. For example with these files:

```
folder1
    first.py
    folder2
        second.py
        folder3
            third.py
```

first.py imports the class in second.py
second.py imports the class in third.py

There's no problem with `python ./folder2/second.py` but `python first.py` gives me an ImportError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "first.py", line 1, in <module>
    from folder2.second import SecondClass
  File "home/test/folder2/second.py", line 1, in <module>
    from folder3.third import ThirdClass
ImportError: No module named 'folder3'
```

It seems first.py executes the `import folder3.third.ThirdClass` of second.py when it tries to import SecondClass from second.py, and because folder3 isn't in its path it raises an error.

If I change the import path in second.py from `from folder3.third import ThirdClass` to `from folder2.folder3.third import ThirdClass`, first.py works, but obviously second.py doesn't work anymore.

Is there a way to solve this?

Edit: Adding
`import sys
sys.path.append("./folder1")`
in `first.py` solves the problem.

Comment: did you put `__init__.py` files in your folders ?

Comment: Make your "folders" packages https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: `__init__.py` is in the folders.  
Thanks for the link, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have worked as is with Python 2, in Python 3 you need to use relative imports withing the package, on other word your `import` line the `second.py` should read:

```
from .folder3.third import ThirdClass
```

Now a slight complication. I am not sure where your package boundary is, if your `first.py` is still part of it or is the main module (meant to be passed directly to the `python` interpreter). Relative imports are based on module name (`__main__` for the main one), main module must use absolute imports.

This has two implications for you. What do `import` statements in `first.py` look like. And also another form your `import` in `second.py` could look like, because based on where you package start, apart from the above give example, you could also say (`first.py` is your main module):

```
from folder2.folder3.third import ThirdClass
```

or (`folder1` and `first.py` are already part of the package and imported from a main module):

```
from folder1.folder2.folder3.third import ThirdClass
```

All the fun details are as always in the corresponding [PEP-328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).